# UI5 OData Search Help not displaying values

Tags: odata, sapui5

this is the odata response i am getting:

[image]

my desired result would be a search help that displays the "TypRolle", "RolleNr" and "RolleOri" columns of the odata response. But right now i am stuck at trying to just display one of them, the "TypRolle" one.

this is what my search help looks like right now:
[image]

As you can see, no values are being displayed.

Here is my valueHelpRequest method:

```
var roletypeUrl = "my odata url";
var attModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var link = this.getView().byId("roletype"); // roletype input field
var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(roletypeUrl, {
    json: true,
    loadMetadataAsync: true
});

oDataModel.read("/ZshNsiAgr01xxlEinzelTypSet", {
            success: function(oData, response) {
                    attModel.setData(oData);

                    var oValueHelpDialog = new sap.m.Popover({
                        title: "Rollentyp auswählen",
                        footer: [new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "Ok"
                        })]
                    });

                    oValueHelpDialog.openBy(link);

                    var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                        title: "test",
                        description: "{TypRolle}"
                    });

                    var oHelpTable = new sap.m.Table({
                        width: "300pt",
                        columns: [
                            new sap.m.Column({
                                header: [
                                    new sap.m.Label({
                                        text: "Rollentyp"
                                    })
                                ]
                            })
                        ],
                        items: {
                            path: "/results",
                            template: oItemTemplate
                        },
                        items: [
                            new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                                cells: [
                                    new sap.m.Text({
                                        text: "{TypRolle}"
                                    })
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })

                    oHelpTable.setModel(attModel);
                    oValueHelpDialog.addContent(oHelpTable);
```

I am very thankful for any kind of suggestion and look forward to your answers :)

Comment: Items aggregation is defined twice (the second is wrong). You should also adjust your template (oItemTemplate) using ColumListItem elements like you do in the second items aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it with JSON model ... here it is

```
                  ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })

                    oHelpTable.bindAggregation("items", "/results", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                      cells: [
                        new sap.m.Text({
                          text: "{TypRolle}"
                        })
                      ]
                    }));

                    oHelpTable.setModel(attModel);
                    oValueHelpDialog.addContent(oHelpTable);
```

Or else you can directly bind to your default OData model as well and it can fetch the data automatically without you writing the `read`